# Replacement of jaxws-spring in Spring 6.1

Tags: xml, spring, jax-ws, java-17, jakarta-migration

I was using jaxws-spring in my project for Spring-JAX WS integration. My current xml configuration looks like this:

```
<beans xmlns: "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core
http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core.xsd
http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet
http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd>

...
...
<wss:binding url="/test/v1">
    <wss:service>
        <ws:service bean="#userbean">
            <ws:handlers>
                <ref bean="testHandler"/>
            </ws:handlers>
        </ws:service>
    </wss:service>
</wss:binding>
```

Now, I am trying to move my application to Spring 6.1 and Java 17 from Spring 4.x and Java 8, which includes javax -> jakarta namespace refactor.
My pom.xml file already contains com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt but I need to add jakarta.xml.ws:jakarta.xml.ws-api also I believe after moving to Java 17.

Since jaxws-spring does not support jakarta version of jaxws, how can I replace above namespaces and schema definitions?

i) One way I found was using Apache CXF library but I couldn't find exact replacements I need to make above. Any references are appreciated.

ii) If I use apache CXF implementation, can com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt and org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws coexist together i.e., won't cause any classpath issue at runtime?

PS: I cannot move away from xml based configuration right now